# Don't understand Python Method

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I don't understand what is going on in the `move` method. I am taking the AI course from Udacity.com. The video location is: http://www.udacity.com/view#Course/cs373/CourseRev/apr2012/Unit/512001/Nugget/480015

Below is the code I don't get, it's not working as shown in the video .. 
The answer I should be getting according to Udacity is [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Here is what I get  `[]`

```
p=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]


def move(p, U):
    q = []
    for i in range(len(p)):
        q.append(p[(i-U) % len(p)])
        return q

print move(p, 1)
```

Comment: Should be moved to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Indentation problem*. You should move your return statement outside the for loop, else it will return immediately after the first iteration: -

```
for i in range(len(p)):
    q.append(p[(i-U) % len(p)])
return q
```

And also, your original code returns `[0]` and not just `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your return shouldn't be indented into the for loop...

```
p=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]


def move(p, U):
    q = []
    for i in range(len(p)):
        q.append(p[(i-U) % len(p)])
    return q

print move(p, 1)
```